# List inside a list android

Tags: android

I want to display a list inside a list in android . what will be the best way to do it. Please help with some example. I have tried using calling an adapter class from adapter(header).

Comment: Go for expandablelistview.

Comment: My requirements will not go for expandableListView. Please suggest me something else.

Comment: @sakshiAgrawal then explain your requirements in the question to make it more clear. Otherwise, you'll just get expandablelistview answers and others like "Don't do it"

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?? I guess expandable listview should do the trick.because using a scroll able content inside another scroll-able content is bad habit.

Comment: I am creating a cart(sort of). I have to display the items grouped by the store name. I have to display the store name and store total price as a heading and the items for that store as a sub category. Plus I have two buttons of '+' and '-' to add the quantity of the item.

Comment: can you add a screenshot in your question?

Comment: okay I got it. try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25102519/add-headers-in-a-listview-using-arrayadapter

Comment: Please take some time to read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to develop expandable list view.

[Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) is sample of it

Answer (score 0):

this effects when it comes to performance of the list view...
the solution is to infliate a new listview inside the main listView, you can do this inside adapters getView method

here is the link - [android: listview in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652814/android-listview-in-listview)

Answer (score 0):

Take a LinearLayout in XML and and make another view for row which you want to add and then inflate row and add to linearlayout.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, just to add to it, the data structure that we send to the Adapter will look like ArrayList<Arraylist<Type>> and also some one else has already done all the complex stuff using expandable list view. 
So I feel it is better  to use that.