# Which layout should I use for scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview

I need to implement a 3 list of items within the same view. Each list of item cannot be scrolled individually, but the whole view could be scrolled. Before, I did it by include 3 ListView within a ScrollView, and then stretch 3 ListView to it's fullest. But that cause some troubles, so I need help. Any ideas how to implement this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-scrollable ListView inside ScrollView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813296/non-scrollable-listview-inside-scrollview)

Comment: I will try that. I did try to make ListView inside ScrollView, but then, if the content displayed varied, the effect is not as expected.

Comment: It didn't behave like I want. If you have a list of contents to display, some need 1 line, some need 4 or 5 lines, then this method is out of question. Because, you will need the exact width inside `onMeasure`. I solved this by render all the views once, then get the exact width and render it again inside the callback. The view appeared is exactly as I wanted, but then there's another problem, because the new `View` create with a total new component (TextView, Button, etc), and I don't want that, that's why I need another method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you want that `Each list of item cannot be scrolled individually`, I'd suggest using a single `ListView` but with sections. There are various tutorials as to how add sections to a `ListView`, quickest one I could find is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18302538/451951).

It'll work, you just need to manage your `getItemViewType(int)` and `getViewTypeCount()` methods properly. So you say you want from 3 different classes. So your `getViewTypeCount()` should return 4
1 - Section Headers
3 - For the 3 different classes, each class will have different view.

And then you need to adjust your views in your `getView()` methods, based upon the position in the list.

Comment: Each list of item, is from different classes, so it may not work.